# React rerender props change vs local state change

Tags: reactjs

Why the component Demo does not rerender on counter change?
I understand that *props.children* are equal to the previous ones, however local state changes, so it should rerender. Is changing local state optimized somehow to detect whether some part of the **Top component** should be rerendered or shouldn`t?

[Children props example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-wozniak-m3up5?file=/src/App.js)

In the second example it does rerender, what is the difference between these examples?

[Local state change](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-smoke-y207m?file=/src/App.js)

In the examples  you can click on button and see in the console whether Demo is rerendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you're passing the `children` which is a part of `props` and essentially on each re-render of `Top` component, the same `children` reference is being returned so React detects that and doesn't re-render the `Demo` component.

In the second case, React will internally execute `React.createElement(...)` again to create the `Demo` component and that's a new reference.

Here is a good line to remember this by :-

> if a React component returns the exact same element reference in its
> render output as it did the last time, React will skip re-rendering
> that particular child

I referred this here - https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#component-render-optimization-techniques

Answer (score 0):

This is because passing `children` argument to the `Top` component you are passing a reference to this object. React can detect that nothing has changed comparing to the previous version so it will not re-render it.

When you are rendering component using name `<Demo />` in your `Top` component you are rendering a new version of `Demo` component every time.